# Make ontology visible to PHP web page using ARC2? Publish online?

Tags: php, sparql, owl, ontology, protege

I have some PHP code this is intended to create a dynamic web page, based on the result of a SPARQL query.  It isn't working right now, and I think that's because my ontology isn't published online yet.  How do I do the publishing part?

```
<html>
  <body>

     <?php
     include_once('semsol/ARC2.php'); /* ARC2 static class inclusion */ 


     $dbpconfig = array
     (
     "remote_store_endpoint" => "http://dbpedia.org/sparql",
     );

     $store = ARC2::getRemoteStore($dbpconfig); 

     if ($errs = $store->getErrors()) 
         {
           echo "<h1>getRemoteSotre error<h1>" ;
         }

         $query = '
                     PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
                     PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
                     PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
                     PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
                     PREFIX uni: <http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#>
                     SELECT ?property ?subject ?prop ?object 
                     WHERE 
                     {
                     uni:Product ?property ?subject .
                     OPTIONAL {?subject ?prop ?object } 

                     }

                     ';


                     $rows = $store->query($query, 'rows'); /* execute the query */

                      if ($errs = $store->getErrors()) 
                      {
                         echo "Query errors" ;
                         print_r($errs);
                      }

          /* display the results in an HTML table */
          echo "<table border='1'>" ;
          foreach( $rows as $row ) 
          { 
            /* loop for each returned row */
            print "<tr><td>" .$row['l'] . "</td><td>" . $row['c']. "</td></tr>";
          }
          echo "</table>"

  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to load the ontology into a triple store that is accessible via HTTP. Or you use the MySQL backend supported by ARC2 (https://github.com/semsol/arc2/wiki/SPARQL-Endpoint-Setup)

Comment: I also don't get why you think that using the DBpedia endpoint will work with your query? Isn't that obvious that this is not the case?

Comment: I know it won't work. I added that and used other available ontologies to check if its working !

Comment: It seems like you don't understand the concepts behinds. Available ontologies are not enough, there has to be some engine that processes your SPARQL query. Just putting the ontology online won't be enough that's why people use triple stores which in fact are databases for RDF based data like your ontology.

Comment: screenshots are not a good way to ask for help.  you should paste the actual code into the question, using the code sample button `{}` button in the toolbar right below the title area.

Comment: Don't add code as an answer, or do you think it answers your initial question?! 
Edit your question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you still interested in this?  The following works for me.  I have tried to illustrate how to **test individual components** of a multi-part system, instead of just building everything, testing the final product and then saying *"it doesn't work."*

Background:  I'm using **Ubuntu 16** server running in **AWS**.  It appears that you might have some experience with **Fuseki** as a backend.  With small modifications, these instructions should be applicable to OSes other than Ubuntu Linux, running in different physical or virtual environments, and for accessing sparql endpoints other than Fuseki.  You could run the PHP script and the Fuseki process on the same servers, or two different servers.

Your prerequisite responsibilities:  a **working webserver & php interpreter**.  The default Ubuntu apache2 and php7 packages worked for me with minimal or zero additional configuration.  [You could follow instructions like these](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04), skipping the MySQL steps.  The same article provides some tips for configuring the firewall.  You're responsible for determining an **appropriate level of world-accessibility.**

- Download (http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/apache-jena-fuseki-2.6.0.tar.gz, for example) and unpack one of the Fuseki 2 archive files
- If you are going to [access the Fuseki dataset manager remotely](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-899), edit the `run/shiro.ini` file to enable an appropriate remote access policy
- For testing/proof-of-concept, cd into the Fuseki directory and start Fuseki like this `./fuseki-server --mem /default`  **Don't close this terminal session!**  You will need to open another session for additional tasks.  A different method for launching Fuseki is required if you want the process and data to persist.
- Use a web browser to visit the Fuseki page, which will be at an address like this:  `http://server.domain:3030`
- Click the *add data* button and upload some data.  I had previously downloaded the [pizza ontology](http://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl) as `pizza.owl` on my local filesystem, so I clicked the `select files...` button, navigated to my `pizza.owl` file, clicked open, and then clicked *upload now*.  If you use the pizza ontology, you should see that roughly 1980 triples are inserted.
- Now, before running any script, do a reality check and run a query within the Fuseki web interface.  (Click the *query* button tab in the upper left.)

#### What toppings are there, and what classes do they belong to?

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?recursiveTopping rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:PizzaTopping .
  ?recursiveTopping rdfs:label ?toppingLabel .
  ?recursiveTopping rdfs:subClassOf ?immediateParent .
  filter(!isBlank(?immediateParent)) 
  filter( ?immediateParent != pizza:PizzaTopping )
}
order by ?immediateParent ?recursiveTopping
```

#### If the SPARQL query works in the Fuseki web interface, you are ready to embed it in a php script/page.

- create a new folder in your web server's root directory.  I'm using Apache httpd on Ubuntu, so that's `/var/www/html`.  You may need to do this as root, like this:  `sudo mkdir /var/www/html/ARC2_pizza`
- cd into the new directory
- copy the source code from the bottom of this message
- tell the computer that you want to past some text into a file:  `cat > index.php`  Then paste in the text from the clipboard.  The required action will depend on the interface you're using.  In a Ubuntu terminal, use Shift-Control-v.  In putty, click the right mouse button.  Or you could use a text editor like nano or gedit to create `index.php`... just remember that editing files in /var/www/html typically requires root privileges, unless you have changed the ownership or access permissions on the directory, which might not be appreciated by your web server.

#### The script's not ready to run yet!

You need to ensure that the ARC2 library is installed, that your script knows where to find it, and that the `remote_store_endpoint` parameter is set to the right address.

There are probably multiple ways to install [ARC2](https://github.com/semsol/arc2).  I used [composer](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-14-04), which in turn can be installed multiple ways, including  apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install composer
```

or curl

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

followed by

`cd /var/www/html/ARC2_pizza
composer require "semsol/arc2": "dev-master"`

With respect to `remote_store_endpoint`:  if you are running the php script on the same server as the Fuseki server (as I do), you can use `localhost`.  Otherwise, use the fully-qualified public IP address or name of the Fuseki server.

Once the script is customized for your circumstances, **test it from the command line** (as opposed to visiting it with a web browser.)

`php /var/www/html/ARC2_pizza/index.php`

The results won't look pretty, but if you look closely, you should see the names of several pizza ingredients, separated with HTML table tags like `...<td><tr>...`

If that worked, you can finally test it from a web browser.  If you have used a setup like mine, point your browser to an address like http://server.domain/ARC2_pizza

If you don't see a table of pizza toppings in your web browser, then there's something wrong with your web server or firewall settings, not with Fuseki, the query, the PHP and ARC2 installations, or the script.

### Here's the source code for `ARC2_pizza/index.php`.

This is based on the same tutorial that your question is based on.  Don't forget to configure your ARC2 location and your endpoint address

```
<html>
  <body>

     <?php

// customize your ARC2 location
     include_once("/var/www/html/phprdftest/arc2-master/ARC2.php");

     $dbpconfig = array
     (
// customize your endpoint address
     "remote_store_endpoint" => "http://localhost:3030/default/query",
     );

     $store = ARC2::getRemoteStore($dbpconfig); 

     if ($errs = $store->getErrors()) 
         {
           echo "<h1>getRemoteSotre error<h1>" ;
         }

         $query = '
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX pizza: <http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?recursiveTopping rdfs:subClassOf+ pizza:PizzaTopping .
  ?recursiveTopping rdfs:label ?toppingLabel .
  ?recursiveTopping rdfs:subClassOf ?immediateParent .
  filter(!isBlank(?immediateParent)) 
  filter( ?immediateParent != pizza:PizzaTopping )
}
order by ?immediateParent ?recursiveTopping
                     ';


                     $rows = $store->query($query, 'rows'); /* execute the query */

                      if ($errs = $store->getErrors()) 
                      {
                         echo "Query errors" ;
                         print_r($errs);
                      }

          /* display the results in an HTML table */
          echo "<table border='1'>" ;
          foreach( $rows as $row ) 
          { 
            /* loop for each returned row */
            print "<tr><td>" .$row['recursiveTopping'] . "</td><td>" . 
              $row['toppingLabel']. "</td><td>" . 
              $row['immediateParent']. "</td></tr>";
          }
          echo "</table>"

  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this help ! This s my first ever internship and you saved it ! :)

Comment: Could you please copy-paste your composer.json file here ?

Comment: I'm glad to hear you're making progress.  I don't think I used a composer.json file for installing ARC2.  I'll double check and update in a few hours.

Comment: When you accessed the php file on the server, did you get a table containing the IRIs of pizza toppings or just the words alone ?

Comment: The output from the query I provided has three columns: IRI for a topping, text label for that topping, and the IRI for any superclass that topping belongs to. Didn't  you run it through the Fuseki web interface like I suggested?

Comment: Yea I got the same too ! I don't want the IRIs. I just need the words alone

Comment: That's reasonable.  Put together a solution for doing that and show it to us.  Hint: you could implement it in the SPARQL query itself, or in the PHP code that determines which items from array $row are included in the table.

Comment: I added this line inside the for loop of the php code                                   $row=str_replace('http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#','',$row);           It worked. Thanks :)

Comment: good job.  you may want to look into *regular expressions* for replacing from `http://` to the last `/` with a little more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows then you need a mysql backup so first install wamp server then phpmyAdmin database then set the configuration in store query command add
Store store->query('http://localhost/filename.owl'). Then run php file using wamp server. you will see rdf/xml values in the database Don't forget to add ARC.php file and your files in www folder before executing

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
  <body>

     <?php
     include_once('semsol/ARC2.php'); /* ARC2 static class inclusion */ 


     $dbpconfig = array
     (
     "remote_store_endpoint" => "http://dbpedia.org/sparql",
     );

     $store = ARC2::getRemoteStore($dbpconfig); 

     if ($errs = $store->getErrors()) 
         {
           echo "<h1>getRemoteSotre error<h1>" ;
         }

         $query = '
                     PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
                     PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
                     PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
                     PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
                     PREFIX uni: <http://www.semanticweb.org/admin/ontologies/2017/4/untitled-ontology-19#>
                     SELECT ?property ?subject ?prop ?object 
                     WHERE 
                     {
                     uni:Product ?property ?subject .
                     OPTIONAL {?subject ?prop ?object } 

                     }

                     ';


                     $rows = $store->query($query, 'rows'); /* execute the query */

                      if ($errs = $store->getErrors()) 
                      {
                         echo "Query errors" ;
                         print_r($errs);
                      }

          /* display the results in an HTML table */
          echo "<table border='1'>" ;
          foreach( $rows as $row ) 
          { 
            /* loop for each returned row */
            print "<tr><td>" .$row['l'] . "</td><td>" . $row['c']. "</td></tr>";
          }
          echo "</table>"

  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this clarification of your question.  I have added the code to the question itself.  I'm thinking this through now.